# Как преобразовать дату в Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Атрибут хранится в формате даты  'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:ss', хочу преобразовать его в такой формат 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm'  подскажите, как я могу это сделать?

Comment: [Data Type Formatting Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) *и так чтобы он считывался как формат даты* В смысле?

Comment: @Akina, в том плане, что если написать вот так: to_char(registration_date, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:MI'), то я преобразую дату в текст, а нужно чтобы оставался датой

Comment: @Akina мне потом этот атрибут, нужно погрузить в систему BI и нужно чтобы он его распознавал как дата(время)

Comment: А это забота BI - распознать, что ей отдают дату. Postgres уже всё сделал, данные отдал в той форме, в которой просили, и дальше не его работа. PS. Кстати, точно нужен 12-часовой формат времени?

Comment: @Akina, благодарю, не заметил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to_char(registration_date, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI')